# LIstview position in android

Tags: android, listview

In my application I have a `listview`. I have to pass the position of the row clicked to the next screen. But it is showing as null ... please help me ...

Here is my listview code:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                    intent.putExtra("Pos", position);
                  }
            });
```

My another screen where I am getting this pos:

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    Intent intent=getIntent();
                    String pos=intent.getStringExtra("Pos");
                    System.out.println("Pos="+pos);
                    int position=Integer.parseInt(pos); 

                }
            });
```

Comment: In first screen(activity), where are you writing the startActivity();  method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
String pos=intent.getStringExtra("Pos");
```

You are passing a int value and you are checking for String value which obviously is not correct.

Change it to,

```
int pos=intent.getIntExtra("Pos");
```

By this, it means that the key for your put Extra Data Types are independent from the type of Data itself. So ensure that you pass it as int and get it as int.

Comment: THanks Andro Selva..Its working..One more i have to write a update query with 1 int (pos) and 1 string as codition:bElow is my query      long id=db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, initialValues, "description" + "="+ update AND category='Income' , null);   but it is showing as error..I searched but i cant get solution.please help me..

Comment: i will accept this answer..I will explain the scenario clearly..From my database table i have to update a particular row (which i selected in listview) by position and a category as income.SO my problem is how can i write an update query with 2 conditions satisfying..I wrote the above code,but its is not correct..I think i have explained clearly???

Comment: I really wish to help you. But I am not that good with the queries.. Hope you get it.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are putting `int` in `intent.putExtra("Pos", position);`

But you are trying to get `String` from

```
String pos=intent.getStringExtra("Pos");
```

Use

```
int pos=intent.getIntExtra("Pos");
```

instead